# How To convert Simple Word to Sphinx4 WSJ like Dictionary Prounounciation?

Tags: dictionary, speech-recognition, cmusphinx, sphinx4

I Have Just Gone Through to this Sphinx4 Speech Recognition,I had implemented it with the helloworld demo of sphinx4,
Now What is Want is To create A dynamic dictionary For the text file given as input,
Right now What i need to do is just create a text file and uplaod in IMTOOLS and then They provide me a .Dict File.

But My requirement is like as the user Type any text in textbox and click a convert button then it automatically convert that word in to WSJ Dcitionary like prounounciation Words,\ E.G. User Type in textbox with the word he want to recognize Let say its a " ANKIT" then it automaticaly convert that word in to wsj dicionary like format as "AE NG K AH T" . please Anyone Can help me Out?or Any suggestion?i want to do That way...hope i explained in good way that you can understand in proper way and give me reply.. "

If any one Providing this service with the payment.then even its ok...

Comment: CMUSphinx project has recently implemented a new G2P framework which you can use in your code. For details check http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/2012/08/gsoc-1012-grapheme-to-phoneme-conversion-in-sphinx-4-%E2%80%93-project-conclusions/ You can use the pretrained G2P models with sphinx4. To download them visit the project page http://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/G2P%20Models/

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easy website that allows you to do that to create a .dic file: http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/tools/lmtool-new.html . Just upload a .txt file with what you would like to add to the dictionary. You can do this multiple times if you have more than a few thousand sentences and then converge them into one file.